# Django nav bar link url isn't working properly?

Tags: html, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to add a link with my index.html page (made from nicepage) in the nav bar as suggest through tutorials {% urls 'homepage' %}

however, it adds to the rest of the link so?
What can I do?
Do I have to create a navbar.html ? is it necessary?

[html page with nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0nrj.png) /
[urls.py file in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5YtF.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I have been trying to add a link with my index.html page (made from nicepage) in the nav bar as suggest through tutorials 

    {% urls 'homepage' %}

however, it adds to the rest of the link so?
What can I do? 
Do I have to create a navbar.html ? is it necessary?  

[html page with nav bar][1] /
[urls.py file in the project][2]/
[url link navbar][3] /
[error adding link to the previous one][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0nrj.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5YtF.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJoRf.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUC7z.png

Comment: please include code fragments as code fragments in your question [edit] the question...

Answer (score 1):

You did not use the `{% url … %}` template tag. You can work with a leading slash like:

```
<!--     ↓ leading slash -->
<a href="/experience">Experience</a>
```

to define an *absolute path* instead of a *relative* path. But it makes more sense to work with the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
<!--     ↓ url template tag   ↓ -->
<a href="{% url 'experience' %}">Experience</a>
```

You should of course not only change the tag for `experience`, but for all the links.

where `experience` is the `name=…` specified in your `path(…)`.

Comment: so what could be changed is the URL path in urls.py ??

Comment: @yedx_1_10: the `urls.py` is not the problem, the links you wrote are the problem, these should use a leading slash (`/`), and drop the `.html` part, and ideally just use the `{% url ... %}` template tag.

Comment: ` {% url 'experience' %}`  should be the link in the html ?

Comment: @yedx_1_10: yes.

Comment: When I jumped from one page to its "subpage", the navbar item became page.html/subpage.html instead of just page.html. Adding that slash corrected the issue.